# How to show only specific x-axis values on datetime axis in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have searched a lot on this topic. I found one answer on stackoverflow, but it is very terse and not helpful to me (since I am very new to both javascript and highcharts). I would appreciate if someone could explain how to do this by modifying my code below.

I have the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
      chart: {
         renderTo: 'divcontainer',
         height: 500
      },
      xAxis: {
         type: 'datetime',
      },
      credits: {
         enabled: false
      },
      series: [{
         data: [
            [Date.UTC(2007,05,29), 300], // This x-axis value should be labeled.
            [Date.UTC(2007,09,03), 300], // NO LABEL for this value
            [Date.UTC(2007,09,04), 200]  // This x-axis value should be labeled.
         ]         
      }]
   });

})
```

This code gives me:

[image]

There are two problems with this.

(1) The starting date June 29, 2007 is not shown. I want that one to appear in the chart. 
(2) I only want to show the dates corresponding to the first and last point in the data series.

I would really appreciate if anyone can show me how to do these two things.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is kinda possible.  This [code here](http://jsfiddle.net/larsenmtl/PyYnF/2/) produces:

[image]

It is not pretty code though.

Comment: Thanks! I like your code for the simplified example I presented. But you are right, for the real case where I have about 10-12 different dates I want to show, there will be many else if statements. Also, there are too many ticks, which I would like to avoid. Anyhow, this is still helpful, so I am going to accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Regarding the **(1)** question, I believe you can't do that in datetime xAxis in *HighCharts*.  When setting that type of axis, the framework calculates the ticks shown in the correspondent axis depending on the data you have.

In answer to the **(2)** question, I believe that so far you can't skip times in the datetime axis.  However, and even though I haven't tried, you might want to look at some workaround using **categories** so you can use a formatter and replace the ticks that you don't want.

Despite all of the above, I did a workaround that you might want to use and that it just needs a little bit of formatting to be **more or less** what you were asking.  Here it is:

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
chart: {
    renderTo: 'container'
},
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    labels: {
        enabled: false
    }

},

series: [{
    dataLabels: {
        enabled:true,
        formatter: function(){
            if(this.point === this.series.data[this.series.data.length - 1])
            {
                return this.x
            }
            if(this.point === this.series.data[0])
            {
                return this.x
            }
        } 
    },
    data: [
        [Date.UTC(2007,05,29), 300], 
        [Date.UTC(2007,09,23), 300], 
        [Date.UTC(2007,09,04), 400]
    ]
}]
```

});

Basically what I do is getting rid of the xAxis labels and just show the date in the point itself for the values that I want (first and last).  Notice that you might want to format how that date is shown because right now is showing the timestamp in ms.

You can see this live in [jsFiddle: xAxis labels deleted](http://jsfiddle.net/HWPSh/1/)

Comment: Thanks, Nobita. Your is a possible solution too, which is good. But I would like the date to show on the axis. If this were the only response, I would have accepted it as the answer. Thanks for replying, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it easily with `.isLast` and `.isFirst`, like this:

```
     xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                labels: {
                    formatter: function() {
                        if(this.isLast || this.isFirst)
                            return [whatever label calculation you need];
                        else return null;
                    },
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Date'
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

Old question, but there's now a cleaner way to do this with [`tickPositions`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPositions).

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
    },
  xAxis: {
     type: 'datetime',
     labels: {
         // When using tickPositions, you'll also need to specify a label format.
         format: '{value:%e. %b}',
     },         
     tickPositions: [Date.UTC(2007,05,29), Date.UTC(2007,09,04)]
  },
  credits: {
     enabled: false
  },
  series: [{
     data: [
        [Date.UTC(2007,05,29), 300], // This x-axis value should be labeled.
        [Date.UTC(2007,09,03), 300], // NO LABEL for this value
        [Date.UTC(2007,09,04), 200]  // This x-axis value should be labeled.
     ]         
  }]
});
```

[JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/JohnnyHK/hc34s4uv/)

Resulting Chart
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting a comma-separated list of values under xAxis:{ categories:[{'5/29/2007', '9/4/2007', '9/23/2008'}] }

and for the chart: { series: [{null}, {300}, {400}] }

I believe you can also use a delegate for the xAxis labels or series labels so that you can test the values against a threshold and drop them out.